# How to express sequence of numbers in yaml

Tags: yaml

Is there any method to express a sequence of numbers in YAML?

To get a sequence from 1 to 100, I can use `list(range(1,101))` in Python, or `seq(1,100)` in R. But do we have any similar way for YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, there is no such provision in any of the YAML specifications.

Of course the program that interprets the YAML file could create an object for the tag `!range` and substitute its nodes with a range:

```
abc: !range 
- 0
- 100
```

but that is at the application level, and YAML doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna use this YAML file in a Snakemake file. I tested your suggestion, but got the following error: "Config file is not valid JSON or YAML. In case of YAML, make sure to not mix whitespace and tab indentation". But actually there's only space in the YAML file, no tab indentation.

Comment: I have no idea what that might be, I have not used snakeyaml. Did you implement a constructor for `!range` yourself, as I instructed the application should do? If not that might be cause for this error.